# Shopify Liquid - Can You Get a Specific Page's Metafields On A Product Page?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-app

I have a product page in my store.  All my products have an associated vendor.  For each vendor, I have a custom Shopify page and on this page is attached several metafields.  Metafields include things like the vendor (company) country, year founded, etc...

On my product page, I would like to show the above info about the vendor.  I can get to the metafields for the vendor if I was on the custom vendor page by using something like:

```
{% assign vendor_country = page.metafields.mynamespace.country %}
```

Is there anyway to get the same metafield info if I was on a product page?  In this case, the context of the Liquid `page` variable would not be correct by default.  I need a way to set this context based on the `product.vendor` variable and then request the custom vendor page data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible if you know the page handle. To do so you will have to make use of **pages** global object. So just get a page by handle and then call the metafields.

Example Code in Product template

```
{{ pages['page-handle'].metafields.namespace.fieldName }}
```

[Global Pages Object](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects#pages)